# HP ENVY 15t. Can see wifi networks but cannot connect

Tags: 14.04, networking, drivers, broadcom, hp

Broadcom Corporation BCM43142 802.11b/g/n [14e4:4365] (rev 01) is really giving me troubles.

I'm having a really hard time getting my wifi to work on my new HP ENVY 15t. I have installed ubuntu 14.04 and I can see wifi networks but I cannot connect. I tried following ubuntu's instructions online for installing the broadcom driver but am not having any success.

```
lspci -nn
00:00.0 Host bridge [0600]: Intel Corporation Skylake Host Bridge/DRAM    Registers [8086:1910] (rev 07)
00:02.0 VGA compatible controller [0300]: Intel Corporation Skylake Integrated Graphics [8086:191b] (rev 06)
00:04.0 Signal processing controller [1180]: Intel Corporation Skylake Processor Thermal Subsystem [8086:1903] (rev 07)
00:14.0 USB controller [0c03]: Intel Corporation Sunrise Point-H USB 3.0 xHCI Controller [8086:a12f] (rev 31)
00:14.2 Signal processing controller [1180]: Intel Corporation Sunrise Point-H Thermal subsystem [8086:a131] (rev 31)
00:15.0 Signal processing controller [1180]: Intel Corporation Sunrise Point-H Serial IO I2C Controller #0 [8086:a160] (rev 31)
00:15.1 Signal processing controller [1180]: Intel Corporation Sunrise Point-H Serial IO I2C Controller #1 [8086:a161] (rev 31)
00:16.0 Communication controller [0780]: Intel Corporation Sunrise Point-H CSME HECI #1 [8086:a13a] (rev 31)
00:17.0 SATA controller [0106]: Intel Corporation Sunrise Point-H SATA Controller [AHCI mode] [8086:a103] (rev 31)
00:1c.0 PCI bridge [0604]: Intel Corporation Sunrise Point-H PCI Express Root Port #5 [8086:a114] (rev f1)
00:1c.5 PCI bridge [0604]: Intel Corporation Sunrise Point-H PCI Express Root Port #6 [8086:a115] (rev f1)
00:1c.6 PCI bridge [0604]: Intel Corporation Sunrise Point-H PCI Express Root Port #7 [8086:a116] (rev f1)
00:1f.0 ISA bridge [0601]: Intel Corporation Sunrise Point-H LPC Controller [8086:a14e] (rev 31)
00:1f.2 Memory controller [0580]: Intel Corporation Sunrise Point-H PMC [8086:a121] (rev 31)
00:1f.3 Audio device [0403]: Intel Corporation Sunrise Point-H HD Audio [8086:a170] (rev 31)
00:1f.4 SMBus [0c05]: Intel Corporation Sunrise Point-H SMBus [8086:a123] (rev 31)
01:00.0 Ethernet controller [0200]: Realtek Semiconductor Co., Ltd. RTL8111/8168/8411 PCI Express Gigabit Ethernet Controller [10ec:8168] (rev 15)
02:00.0 Network controller [0280]: Broadcom Corporation BCM43142 802.11b/g/n [14e4:4365] (rev 01)
03:00.0 Unassigned class [ff00]: Realtek Semiconductor Co., Ltd. RTS522A PCI Express Card Reader [10ec:522a] (rev 01)

iwconfig
eth0      no wireless extensions.

wlan0     IEEE 802.11abg  ESSID:off/any  
      Mode:Managed  Access Point: Not-Associated   
      Retry short limit:7   RTS thr:off   Fragment thr:off
      Power Management:off

lo        no wireless extensions.


 ifconfig
eth0      Link encap:Ethernet  HWaddr 70:5a:0f:65:11:ee  
      inet addr:138.67.20.127  Bcast:138.67.63.255  Mask:255.255.192.0
      inet6 addr: fe80::725a:fff:fe65:11ee/64 Scope:Link
      UP BROADCAST RUNNING MULTICAST  MTU:1500  Metric:1
      RX packets:158445 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 frame:0
      TX packets:6696 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 carrier:0
      collisions:0 txqueuelen:1000 
      RX bytes:33132453 (33.1 MB)  TX bytes:940902 (940.9 KB)

lo        Link encap:Local Loopback  
      inet addr:127.0.0.1  Mask:255.0.0.0
      inet6 addr: ::1/128 Scope:Host
      UP LOOPBACK RUNNING  MTU:65536  Metric:1
      RX packets:12679 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 frame:0
      TX packets:12679 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 carrier:0
      collisions:0 txqueuelen:0 
      RX bytes:5279387 (5.2 MB)  TX bytes:5279387 (5.2 MB)

wlan0     Link encap:Ethernet  HWaddr 48:e2:44:d7:b0:79  
      inet6 addr: fe80::4ae2:44ff:fed7:b079/64 Scope:Link
      UP BROADCAST MULTICAST  MTU:1500  Metric:1
      RX packets:0 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 frame:434
      TX packets:0 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 carrier:0
      collisions:0 txqueuelen:1000 
      RX bytes:0 (0.0 B)  TX bytes:0 (0.0 B)
      Interrupt:17
```

I am happy to post any information you may need to help me with this issue. I have tried running

```
sudo apt-get --reinstall install bcmwl-kernel-source
```

Since I know it is a broadcom wifi card. I tried looking at the rfkill list and everything is unblocked. Please help I'm becoming very discouraged

Comment: Have you updated all the packages yet?

Comment: I have considered trying this. Will I be able to upgrade to 16.04 when its out in april if I do this? Sorry I've been learning as I go

Comment: Yes, you will be able to.  As a side note, after upgrading, I recommend running `aptitude` and making sure there are no packages in the "Obsolete and Locally Created Packages" category (the category will not show if there are no packages in it).  If there are any, post another question with the names of the packages.

Comment: Sounds good Thank you. I am going try 15.10 and see if that works.

Comment: I just finished the installation of 15.10 and I am having the same issue. I can see available wifi networks but am unable to connect

Comment: @Casey. I too have the same broadcom wifi card on my desktop and it's working fine with Ubuntu 14.04 LTS

Comment: @user4901968. That's a totally wrong suggestion. No need to upgrade to 15.10 just for that.

Comment: @Casey. Try this link(http://askubuntu.com/questions/425155/my-wireless-wifi-connection-does-not-work-what-information-is-needed-to-diagnos) and this script(https://github.com/UbuntuForums/wireless-info) and try to debug your issue.

Comment: Thank you for your suggestion. I'm glad to have people chiming in to help. The situation was a little more involved. when I first installed 14.04 as you said the wifi was fine. But it would not work with the power cord plugged in. I know weird right? I then proceeded to reinstall 14.04 thinking I had made a mistake. This is where the trouble began.... upon reinstalling 14.04 I had no wifi. 15.10 didn't help but it apparently has a bug where 802.1x supplicant waits to long. I switched down to 15.04 where this bug is supposed to not be an issue to no avail.

Comment: also great script. All the info I had been looking at and more